# Visual Studio cant see open files as different tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Every time i select a another file it removes Style.css and you can only see that file, i want to see all the open files side by side in a tab view

Answer (score 0):

I Went to Preferences and added

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": true
```

to the file

Comment: and that fixed your issue, @Adam?